# TypeError: Invalid rect assignment

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to make a game but I keep running into the error Invalid Rect Assignment. I don't know why, or what's going on.

Here is the code:

```
class Tile(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, pos, size):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface((size, size))
        self.image.fill('grey')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft = pos)
```

Kpie --

Here is the other code:

```
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
def __init__(self, pos):
    super().__init__()
    self.image = pygame.Surface((32, 64))
    self.image.fill('red')
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft = pos)
    self.direction = pygame.math.Vector2(0, 0)
```

and:

```
def run(self):

    #Level Tiles

    self.tiles.update(self.world_shift)
    self.tiles.draw(self.display_surface)
    
    # Player

    self.player.update()
    self.player.draw(self.display_surface)
```

Code leading to problem:

```
player = Player(200)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and make sure you understand that this is *not a discussion forum*. We are not interested in your programing background; we *are* interested in 1) a *clearly asked, specific question* that explains *what we need to tell you*, even after your best attempt to solve the problem yourself; 2) a [complete](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146) error message that [is produced by the code that you show, without modification or filling in extra context](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: What is pos? Can you include the code that calls this constructor?

Comment: how did you initialize Tile?

Comment: navylover -- def __init__(self, pos, size)

Comment: Please include the full error text in your question.  Please include the code that is leading to the error.  For example, the call to `Player()` or `Tile()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> player = Player(200)

This is the issue.  When the constructor of `Player()` is called, it's being given a `pos` argument of 200.  This is then later user with `get_rect( topleft = pos )`.

Looking at the [documentation](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html?highlight=get_rect#pygame.Surface.get_rect) for get_rect(), the given position is a tuple, a *pair* of co-ordinate values.

So try:

```
player = Player( ( 200, 200 ) )
```

Where the 200,200 is the position you wish the sprite to originate.